# C/UNIX read from input (limited by char count and timeout)

Tags: c, unix, timeout, buffer, polling

while studying for my finals I found a very interesting questing. This is what I desire to code.

Program read stdin into buffer (of fixed size). When buffer is full, program prints it to file. But if buffer isn't filled in fixed time (timeout), program prints to file `[TIMEOUT]` and the rest of buffer (currently read)

**First example:**

buffer_size = 5; timeout = 4;

`$ while : ; do printf 1; sleep 1; done | ./a.out`

should write `[TIMEOUT]1111[TIMEOUT]1111[TIMEOUT]1111` etc. because while-loop writes only 4 chars (within 4 second limit).

**Second example**

buffer_size = 3; timeout = 5;

`$ while : ; do printf 1; sleep 1; done | ./a.out`

should write `111 111 111` etc. because while-loop writes 3 chars (within 3 seconds < 5 sec limit) so timeout never happens.

I'm trying to code it using `poll` but I don't know how to find out, whether all chars have been written or only one. I can't also get stuck on `read(0, buffer, buffer_size)` as I would miss timeout. Is it even possible? I guess it is as our teacher pointed it out as a good excersice.

Of course, busy wait is unacceptable, only classic POSIX syscalls allowed (poll, select, read, write, open...).

Could anybody hint me, please? I have no clue how to manage this behaviour and neighter stackoverflow nor google gave me answer (or maybe I just don't know what to search for)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wrote an example of using `poll` to set a timeout with `scanf` in my answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197977/how-can-i-prevent-scanf-to-wait-forever-for-an-input-character/21198375#21198375. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys, I figured it out in other way (but still no busy-wait). I attach the code below for further students :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>

extern char ** environ;

/*
usage:

$ while : ; do printf 1; sleep 1; done | XTIMEOUT=4 XSIZE=5 ./a.out
[TIMEOUT]1111[TIMEOUT]1111[TIMEOUT]1111...

$ while : ; do printf 1; sleep 1; done | XTIMEOUT=5 XSIZE=3 ./a.out
111...
*/

uint64_t
now()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    double time_in_mill =  (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000;
    return (uint64_t) time_in_mill;
}

int
main(int argc, char ** argv) { 

    //  ----------------------------------
    //  boring stuff

    size_t timeout = 11 * 1000;
    size_t buffer_size = 10;

    char * tmp_env;
    if ((tmp_env = getenv("XTIMEOUT")) != NULL) {
        timeout = atoi(tmp_env) * 1000;
    }
    if ((tmp_env = getenv("XSIZE")) != NULL) {
        buffer_size = atoi(tmp_env);
    }

    //  ----------------------------------
    //  fun starts here

    //  buffers
    char * buffer = (char *) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char));
    char * buffer2 = (char *) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(char));

    //  set stdin non-blocking
    int saved_flags = fcntl(0, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(0, saved_flags | O_NONBLOCK);


    //  poll structure
    struct pollfd ufds[1];
    ufds[0].fd = 0;
    ufds[0].events = POLLIN;

    int rv, n, k;
    size_t pos = 0;
    uint64_t start_time;

    int rem_time = timeout;

    for (;;) {
        start_time = now();
        //printf("pollig for %d\n", rem_time);
        rv = poll(ufds, 1, rem_time);

        if (rv == -1) {     //  err
            err(1, "poll");
        }
        else if (rv == 0) { //  timeout
            write(1, "[TIMEOUT]", 9);
            write(1, buffer, pos);
            pos = 0;
            rem_time = timeout;
        }
        else {      //  regular
            if (ufds[0].revents & POLLIN) {     //  real action
                if ((n = read(0, buffer2, buffer_size-pos)) == -1) {    //  read up to free space
                    err(1, "read");
                }

                for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {   //  copy (maybe strcp)
                    buffer[k+pos] = buffer2[k];
                }

                pos += n;   //  pos has changed

                if (pos == buffer_size) {   //  buffer is full -> write it out and set new timeout
                    write(1, buffer, buffer_size); write(1, "", 1);
                    pos = 0;
                    rem_time = timeout;
                }
                else {      // still not enough, make timeout shorter (by the length of computation)
                    rem_time = rem_time - now() + start_time;
                }
            }
            else {      //  poll failed!
                err(1, "false alarm");
            }
        }
    }

    free(buffer);
    free(buffer2);

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

1. Use `select()` with a timeout
2. Set the FD to `O_NONBLOCK` with `fcntl`
3. Only read from the FD when `FD_ISSET` returns true
4. Read until you get `EWOULDBLOCK` or `EAGAIN` (which indicate timeout). Repeat the loop if you see `EINTR`.

Here is a better answer: go to your library and get a copy of Stephens out. I believe it's this book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Environment-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0321637739](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739)
you want (all of his are great). However, this is *still* the canonical reference volume to teach you how to do this stuff and should be a core text for your course.

Comment: thankx for hints, but it actually doesn't work (at least my implementation)... I'll post code in answer for everybody to see.