# Function that gets char instantly without pressing enter

Tags: c++, while-loop, escaping, getchar, enter

I'm new to programming, and I try to program a menu in C++.

I want it to be in a `while` loop, breaking when <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed, but I want the character to be read instantly without having to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
while (breaker != 27)
{
    //menu based on switch(breaker)
}
```

I found the `getch()` function and `<conio.h>` header, but people say not to use it because it works only on Windows.

Is there any other method that I can get a character without pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and it's multiplatform/meets coding ethic?

My operating system is Windows 11, but I would like to know the solution that works on other systems.

Comment: That's not something you can do with standard C++, it's controlled by the terminal. But depending on the operating system and the terminal, it can be done in other ways.

Comment: This is a limitation (feature) of the console. I/O is under the purview of the operating system, so any I/O scheme you want will need to be supported by the OS you're using. What OS do you want to support?

Comment: Thanks, so If I would use other type of "medium" such as some graphic engine (I found builder in tutorials) I could do it other way?

Comment: Yes, you need some sort of graphics library that has already made the heavy lifting for it to be cross-platform. SFML and Qt comes to mind depending on your use-case.

Comment: NCurses library can be used for this : https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html. Home page : https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html#h3-documentation

Comment: Voted to reopen. The question is precise and clear. Closing it for needing “details or clarity” is inappropriate.

Comment: There are libraries and system-specific function which can bypass the line-buffering on the console or terminal, but it's not possible with plain standard C++. So please [edit] your question to tell us your operating system.

Comment: I edited my question, so you can see my OS type

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not possible to use the functions provided by the ISO C++ standard library to detect whether the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key has been pressed. However, most platforms provide a platform-specific API which does provide this functionality.

On Microsoft Windows, you can use the functions [`_getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170), [`_getche`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getche-getwche?view=msvc-170) or [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput).

On Linux, you can use the [ncurses library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: Thanks, I'll use _getch then, It's simpliest (for me) I think.

Comment: @Radek: `_getch` and `_getche` are simplest to use, but `ReadConsoleInput` is more flexible. For example, when using `ReadConsoleInput`, you can wait for user input with a timeout, by combining that function with `WaitForSingleObject`. See [this answer of mine to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72394274/12149471) for an example.