# Why CancelIoEx doesn't cancel getline completely and need twice enter to trigger next getline?

Tags: c++, windows, console, cancelio

Here is a C++ example.

Each 7 seconds, `CancelIoEx()` is called and user needs to fill in the content twice (by hit Enter key twice) to trigger `getline()`.

I guess something in Windows Console may not be canceled by `CancelIoEx()` properly can cause this issue?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
HANDLE hStdin = nullptr;

void readInput() {
    string input;
    while (true) {
        cout << endl << "input: ";
        getline(std::cin, input);
        if (cin.good())
            cout << "got msg: " << input << std::endl;
        else
        {
            cin.clear();
        }
    }
}

void CancelInputPeriodically() {
    while (true) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(7));
        CancelIoEx(hStdin, nullptr);
        cout << "time's up!!!" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    thread cancelThread(CancelInputPeriodically);

    readInput();

    cancelThread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I try to set breakpoint at `getline()`, and it really doesn't receive my first Enter hit.

A workaround is using `WriteConsoleInput()` to send `VK_RETURN` after cin EOF.

Answer (score 1):

`CancelIoEx` is a Windows function. It cancels other Windows IO calls. It does not guarantee anything about `std::getline` from Visual Studio's Standard Library implementation.

There's no equivalent to `CancelIOEx` in Visual Studio's Standard Library. If you need that, you'll need to reimplement the `streambuf` from `std::cin` to get guaranteed results. But this will be quite tricky for you, as the question shows that you're not familiar with the layered structure here.

Comment: Thanks!
I don't think I'm the only person who encounter this issue. I'm wondering how to achieve my goal in another proper way?

Comment: @JackKuo: I'm not entirely sure that we understand what your precise goal is. There's some hints about an "XY problem" - you might want to look back and see what business problem motivated you to look at `CancelIoEx`.

Answer (score 1):

The function [`CancelIoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelioex-func) is a function from the Windows API. It is designed for cancelling certain other function calls from the Windows API. It is not designed for cancelling function calls from the C++ standard library, such as [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Although it may be possible to achieve the desired effect using your approach, this is generally not recommended.

If you want to read input from a Windows Console, and want to be able to interrupt this input operation at any time, then I recommend that you do not use `std::getline` or `CancelIoEx`, but rather [`WaitForMultipleObjects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects).

The function `WaitForMultipleObjects` allows you to wait for multiple objects at once, and to return as soon as one of them is in a signalled state. These objects can be, among other things, Console Input, [Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects) or [Waitable Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects).

This means that using the function `WaitForMultipleObjects`, you can wait for either of the following to happen:

- The user presses a key.
- An object indicating a cancellation request is put into a signalled state.

This cancellation request could be implemented as either an Event that is set by another thread, or as a Waitable Timer. The function `WaitForMultipleObjects` is able to wait on both types of objects. Alternatively, if all you need is a simple timeout, you can use the function [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) instead of `WaitForMultipleObjects`, because the function `WaitForSingleObject` allows you to specify a timeout value, in addition to a handle to an object on which to wait.

Once the function `WaitForSingleObject`/`WaitForMultipleObjects` reports that new console input is available, you can read it using the function [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput). The function [`ReadConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) will not work reliably, for the reason stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72394274/12149471).

See [this answer of mine to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72394274/12149471) for a working example program.

Note that this solution will require you to read a single keypress at once. You won't be able to read a whole line at once.